# Select row from data Grid View and select

Tags: grid

I have a test case for users which i want to select a user from User Group and delete only GUEST user.

please find below screen shot.

**1.**

[image]

**2.**

[image]

in advance thanks.

Comment: i really don't know what you are asking. you just give the link picture and after then what?

Comment: Hi Dwi,Actually i want to delete the Guest user row who is under the User Group.